# How to access review_history for Anonymous

Tags: workflow, plone, history, review

I'm having trouble accessing the review_history using the `getInfoFor` method, example code below :

```
<div tal:define = "review_history python:wtool.getInfoFor(here, 'review_history', []);
                   review_history python: portal.reverseList(review_history)"
 tal:repeat="items review_history">
 <span tal:content="python: review_history" />
 </div>
```

When I'm logged in to the system I can see the contents of the review_history var, but when I view as an unregistered user, all I see is an empty list. Has anyone ever come across this and is there a way to amend it so that its available to everybody?

Comment: I've been reading up on this and discovered that review_history does now allow access to anonymous users, I havn't come across any information on how to allow access to unauthenticated users. Any help advice would be much appreciated, 

Regards
Ruth

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you'd want to do is either adjust a workflow or, even better, create a custom workflow. In this workflow you can manage the permissions on your content and add that anonymous users are allowed to view the history of objects. (Don't forget to apply your new workflow to the content types of which you want to make the history available for anonymous users.)

Take a look at [Creating Workflows in Plone](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/creating-workflows-in-plone) or [Understanding permissions and security](http://plone.org/documentation/kb/understanding-permissions) on plone.org. Those pages should get you going in the right direction.